# syntax for everything after string? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I want to make the following code much shorter. I need to make it so that everything after /users/1/... is okay and /users/1 is okay. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

```
<%if request.path == "/users/#{current_user.id}" or request.path == "/users/#{current_user.id}/listeners" or request.path == "/users/#{current_user.id}/listening" or request.path == "/users/#{current_user.id}/discovered" %>
```

I guess in CSS it's similar to ^=

Answer (score 2):

How about params comparison? It all probably happens within `users` resource, so this segment of url will be stored in `params[:id]` and we can compare it with current user id doing:

```
<% if params[:id].to_i == current_user.id %>
```

or, as you probably set `@user` variable in this controller:

```
<% if @user == current_user %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`starts with?`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/StartsEndsWith/starts_with?) to check if the beginning of the string matches 'users/1' etc, or you can use `.include?` to find the string anywhere.

```
# starts with:
<%if request.path.starts_with?("/users/#{current_user.id}/") %>
# include:
<%if request.path.include?("/users/#{current_user.id}/") %>
```

If you are trying to find out if the user is on a users controller action then you can check the controller param value instead:

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'users' %>
```

If you want to know if the user viewing the page is the same as the user being viewed (eg. a user looking at their own account page), you can compare the current user to the @user object that your methods instantiate:

```
<% if current_user == @user %>
```

Comment: there is the issue that if a user has an ID 1 or 1000 this will trigger

Comment: @APJ do you want to say that it should trigger only for user_ids 1 or 1000.

Comment: @APJ not if you include a trailing /, edited the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: looks like then this is the shortest I can get: <%if request.path == "/users/#{current_user.id}" or request.path.includes?("/users/#{current_user.id}/") %> sound about right?

Comment: @APJ Are you just trying to check if the current page is within the users controller? If so you can just check the `params[:controller]` value, will add this to the answer.

Comment: Also the includes throws an error when Im just at the root path saying it doesnt understand "includes?" for a '/'. No wasn't trying the controller thing but thats cool didn't know that

Comment: @APJ Sorry it's `include` not `includes`, take the s off. Will update. Do your controller actions instantiate a @user object from the id? If so you can compare `@user` to `current_user`.